# Disabling sleep doesn't seem to work for my app

Tags: android, react-native, download, sleep

I'm writing a react-native app. It downloads a list of files from a server (one at a time). I'm using react-native-fetch-blob with android download manager. So i have a notification with a progress bar for each file.
My problem is that if I leave the app and do other things, not all the files get downloaded. Then when I come back to the app, I can see that it refreshes (white screen for a second and back to first screen of the app).
I've disable sleep for this app in android battery settings but it seems that it goes to sleep anyway.

It's also worth noting that it happens when i start using more than 2 apps. It seems that my phone can handle 2 awaken apps, but as soon as i use a 3rd one, it will put to sleep one of the 2 other apps.

Any ideas of what's wrong?
ps: I'm on a Galaxy A3 2016 and Android 7.0